# Events with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, social-gaming

I have a rails application with devise users. 
I'm trying to run the gamification gem [gioco](https://rubygems.org/gems/gioco).

In my console I can create events for the users with:

```
User.first.track_event('Published a post')
```

and this let me create points in the user dashboard.

that's my print screen [Print screen](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s447/sh/287ffc63-14f8-4ddd-a36a-f2195ef5a170/225e6a15bc3caecd4c18568521d2b11e)

I want to connect my model publish a post, with the events that I can create in the console, but i don't know how to do this.

Any of you have suggestions for doing that?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you tried so far? Please post code where people can look and give help.

Comment: I installed the gem gioco.pro from my heroku server. And create settings for giving a point when i publish a post. In my console when i put User.first.track_event('Published a post') the settings work and i can see the points assignment in my screen. This is my Dream/view : <%= current_user.gioco_data %>
In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaiaCoptnhE explains the proces. I did all. The problem is that i have to connect the action publish a micropost with the event micropost published in the console. How to do that?